# How do I change the number of open files limit in Windows without code changes?

Tags: windows, file

Is there a way to increase file limit without any code changes? I was able to increase open file limit using _setmaxstdio but for existing customers we don't want to change binaries and we are trying to resolve it without any code changes.

Comment: No, it can't be changed _outside_ your program because a call to _setmaxstdio must be done...

Comment: Note that this is a limit in the C runtime the application(s) are using, not in Windows itself.

Answer (score -2):

It is `FILES=` entry in `c:\config.sys`.

Comment: No...config.sys is a there but nothing uses it. Moreover _setmaxstdio sets something completely different (limited but separated by maximum number of open files at operating system level).

Comment: I am not sure what exactly wants the author with "change the number of open files limit". Also, not sure whether `config.sys/files=` is supported under Windows 7. But what you think is the purpose of Files= in Config.sys? There is analog named Config.nt on newer Windows-es.

Comment: `config.sys` is there for **MS-DOS emulation** (where possible), it has **nothing to do with Windows** (same as `config.nt`). Theoretic limit for network files (depends on version!) is 16384 (check with `net config server`) but this default value is also limited by physical memory. Limit for local files...well...in theory it's limited by memory only and maximum number of kernel objects (2^24 for 32 bit Windows but remember that count includes every other kernel object!!!) but I never met that limit...

Comment: In other words - there is no need to change any number of files... But we don't know the Windows version for this question. It can be 98/Me for example. Otherwise, why asking?

Comment: LOL! If it is Win98 then he had to tag also with MS-DOS ;) He is asking because CRT has its own limits. No matters OS limits if you're programming in C you're internally limited: _low level_ functions (like `_open()`) usually set this limit to 2048 (plus `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`). Higher level `stdio` functions have another limit to 512 (it's the limit he changes with `_setmaxstdio`).

Comment: If 512 open files are not enough, I think there is wrong design of software.